# Correct database operation to get the data desired

Tags: mysql, database

Ok, so I've got a MySQL database with several tables. One of the tables (table A) has the items of most interest to me.

It has a column called `type` and a column called `entity_id`. The primary key is something called `registration_id`, which is more or less irrelevant to me currently.

Ultimately, I want to gather all items of a particular `type`, but which have a unique `entity_id`. The only problem with this is that `entity_id` in table A is NOT a unique key. It is possible to have multiple `registration_ids` per `entity_id`.

Now, there's another table (table B) which has only a list of unique `entity_ids` (that is, it is the primary key on that table), however there's no information on the `type` in that table.

So with these two tables, what is the best way to get the data I want?

I was thinking some sort of way (DISTINCT) that I could use on the first table, alone, or possibly a join of some sort (I'm still relatively new to the concept of joins) between table A and table B, combining the `entity_id` from table B with the `type` from table A.

What's the most efficient database operation for this for now? And should I (eventually, not right now as I simply do not have the time, sadly) change the database structure for greater efficiency?

If anyone needs any additional information or graphics, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use either `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT entity_id
  FROM table1
 WHERE type = ?
 GROUP BY entity_id
```

or `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT entity_id
  FROM table1
 WHERE type = ?
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ed01/1)** demo

Comment: I've never used the GROUP BY SQL function before. I'll have to look into the documentation for it. The query on it is faaaaar faster than for the second condition, and I can only imagine that is true with more records.

Comment: Great. Definitely look it up. It might be a good opportunity to start using grouping and aggregates in SQL. FYI [In most cases, a DISTINCT clause can be considered as a special case of GROUP BY. For example, the following two queries are equivalent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

Answer (score 1):

Table Joins are a costly operation. If you are dealing with large datasets then the time it takes to execute a join operation is non-negligible.

The following SQL statement will grab all entity_id's and group them by type. So for each entity_id only 1 of each type will be in the result set:

```
SELECT type, entity_id FROM TableA GROUP BY type, entity_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Try this to give you the types that have only one (unique) entity_id.

```
SELECT type , count(entity_id)
  FROM table1
GROUP BY type
HAVING COUNT(entity_id)=1
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13a5a/3)

Comment: I got this: Invalid use of group function: SELECT type , count(entity_id) FROM table1 WHERE count(entity_id) < 2

Comment: Yea i realised .. wait ill try it and then post

Comment: Ok try this @AndrewAlexander this is working and it will give you the unique `entity_ids` also you can skip the `count(enity_id)` in the first line that is just to verify  :)

Comment: Did it work @AndrewAlexander ? sorry for the confusion took time to get around sql fiddle schema

Comment: Ah, it only got the value assigned to type3.

Comment: Thats what you want right ? types having unique `enity_id`s .. or did i understand wrong ?